# Cannot pip install SolrClient (python2.6 vs 3.4 issues?)

Tags: solr, centos, pip, python-3.4, python-2.6

I am trying to pip install [SolrClient](https://github.com/moonlitesolutions/SolrClient), and I believe I am having some difficulty with my version of python.

Here is the error message.

```
[root@centos64 ~]# pip install SolrClient
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
Collecting SolrClient
Using cached SolrClient-0.1.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-UeQsqQ/SolrClient/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    import SolrClient
  File "SolrClient/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .solrclient import SolrClient
  File "SolrClient/solrclient.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .collections import Collections
  File "SolrClient/collections.py", line 7, in <module>
    from collections import defaultdict
ImportError: cannot import name defaultdict

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-UeQsqQ/SolrClient/
```

So, when I go to check my python version, it is 2.6

```
[root@centos64 ~]# python -V
Python 2.6.6
```

I've got python 3.4 on my machine, albeit I need to call it like this

```
[root@centos64 ~]# python3.4 -V
Python 3.4.3
```

So, a few questions.

Am I correct in my assumption that my error is due to the fact that I am attempting to pip install using python2.6?

If so, how do I either

a) tell pip to use the python3.4 version? (not sure if this is the right way of thinking about it)

b) adjust my system to use python3.4

Otherwise, I am not sure how to proceed here. Thoughts?

Comment: `Am I correct in my assumption that my error is due to the fact that I am attempting to pip install using python2.6?` - yes. The clean way to handle this situation is to create a virtualenv and put as as default python in your `PATH`

Comment: Using pew I am assuming?

Comment: i just clicked on the link for SolrClient you have provided and i saw that it was clearly written that it required py3.3 and above means it will not work on python2.x

Answer (score 1):

I did indeed need to use python3.4

As suggested, I went with a virtual environment for the task.

```
pip install pew

pew new -p `which python3.4` 3.4

pew workon 3.4

pip install SolrClient
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3 <envname>
cd <envname>
source bin/activate
pip install SolrClient
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: its simple as that they have not supported python 2.x versions, you can only install it for python 3.3+ .

Comment: if you dont want virtualenv and want to install globally. then use this   'python3 -m pip install SolrClint' .